# matlab parfor unable to classify the variable

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, parfor

I'm trying to run a parfor loop to speed up everything.
I've not completely understood the use of sliced variables.

What I want to do is to generate within the parfor a struct `M` storing all the figures with a getframe(fig) inside the function `ThicknessVideoCreatorV2` needed to create a video. Within the loop the `Mtemp` struct with 'cdata' and 'colormap' variables is created and then assigned to the kk position of `M`.

```
iV=(iStart:iFinish)+Divid-iStart;  
    istop=min(iV(end)+iStart,nImag-iStart);
    
    M=[];
    
    parfor i=iStart:iStart+100%iStop
        kk=i-iStart+1;
        zz=iV(kk);
%         iV=i+Divid-iStart;  
        
%         if iV+iStart>nImag-iStart
%             
%             break
%     
%         else
        
             Mtemp=ThicknessVideoCreatorV2(LFradial(:,i), TfilmRadial(:,i),...
                 txt1{i}, txt2{i}, txt3{i},newIred{zz},fig, i, p1,p2,pl2,...
                 imgGraph, t1, t2,t3, pipeLength,limY_TBS);

             M(kk)=Mtemp;

    end
```

I get this error:

"Error: Unable to classify the variable 'M' in the body of the parfor-loop. For more information, see Parallel for Loops in
MATLAB, "Solve Variable Classification Issues in parfor-Loops"."

How can I fix this and use parfor properly?

Thank you in advance

Riccardo

Comment: Pre-allocating `M` would help the compiler "know" what it's meant to be, currently you're dynamically expanding its size in parallel, i.e. out of order, which is likely to not end well. If you're expecting `Mtemp` to be a figure then I think you could initialise `M = gobjects(100,1);` or you can use `M = cell(100,1);` but then you'll need to assign using `M{kk} = Mtemp` (curly braces)

Comment: If preallocation by itself does not solve the problem, the computed `kk` index could be part of the issue. Try making the loop over `kk`, then compute `i`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rules for "sliced" output variables in `parfor` basically come down to the constraint that you must assign based on the loop index. You are allowed to offset the loop index in the assignment, but your case doesn't fit into the current constraints (See "form of indexing" [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/sliced-variable.html)). In this case, the simplest thing to do is swap `i` and `kk`

```
parfor kk = 1:100
    i = kk + iStart - 1;
    M(kk) = ...
end
```

Unfortunately, this will stop your inputs from being sliced - but that shouldn't stop the loop running.

Comment: Thank you! after many weeks I'm finally able to run the parfor-loop by doing what you suggested, and it works perfectly.

Comment: Glad it works for you - please "accept" the answer. (And I'm sad it took so long...)